# Deep linking on S3 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3, deployment, angular5

I have succesfully deployed my angular5 app to:
`http://myApp.s3domain.amazonaws.com`

Angular router automatically routes me to `http://myApp.s3domain.amazonaws.com/home`

My app is built in such a way, that a parameter is used like so: `http://myApp.s3domain.amazonaws.com/home/uniqueParameter`

This redirecrs to my `error.html`, instead of the link. It works locally.

How do i implement correct deep linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i fixed this by using firebaseapp instead and setting `firebase.json` to

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It works now.